# How to remove the WordPress logo from login and register page?

Tags: login, user-registration, logo

I want to remove WordPress logo from login and register page. I think I have to make some changes in .css file for this. So I want to know in which css file do I have to make the changes?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a filter to `login_head`. As explained in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_head), add this to your code:

```
function my_custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
    h1 a {background-image:url(http://example.com/your-logo.png) !important; margin:0 auto;}
    </style>';
}
add_filter( 'login_head', 'my_custom_login_logo' );
```

Comment: `login_head` is action, not a filter :) , however `login_headerurl` is filter ...

Comment: topic starter asks to remove logo, not to replace... if he uses this, page will result a 404 error...

Answer (score 1):

To remove the WordPress logo, paste the below code in functions.php of the theme directory.

```
function remove_logo() { ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .login h1 a { display: none; }
</style>
<?php }

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_logo' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your website Editor using > **Appearance > Editor > function.php** and add this before the last line "**?>**":

```
/* Remove WP logo from login page */

function custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type ="text/css">.login h1 a { display:none!important; }</style>';
}

add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_logo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the logo using built-in theme editor as explained
[in this post](https://www.geekinsta.com/how-to-change-wordpress-logo-in-the-login-page/).

Step 1:

Login to your WordPress site as admin and go to **Media** -> **Add New** to upload a new image and copy the image url.

You can also upload your new logo to the theme’s images directory or you can create a new directory to upload the logo. This can be done with the help of web hosting control panel or FTP.

Step 2:

Go to the Admin **Dashboard** -> **Appearance** -> **Theme Editor**.

Step 3:

When the editor opens, find and select functions.php from the right side of the page and add the following code to the end of the page.

```
function my_custom_logo() { ?>
     <style type="text/css">
         #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
             background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png);
             height:100px;
             width:100px;
             background-size: 100px 100px;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             margin-bottom: 10px;
         }
     </style>
 <?php } 
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_logo' );
```

Replace *logo.png* with the name of the file you have uploaded. If you have uploaded the new logo with WordPress, modify the background-image property as shown below.

**background-image: url(url copied in step 1);**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through the coding, use [Custom Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login/) plug-in to do that

Answer (score 0):

It's best to run this after login_enqueue_scripts as mentioned by @ashin [above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185530/how-to-remove-the-wordpress-logo-from-login-and-register-page/350927#350927)

I'll post this since it relates to changing the logo.

To change the URL from wordpress.org to your own (along with the links title attr), use this:

```
    function my_login_logo_url() {
        return home_url();
   }
    add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );

    function my_login_logo_url_title() {
        return 'Your Site Name and Info';
    }
    add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

If you want to get crazy with styling, here is the css used to edit the entire login page:

```
body.login {}
body.login div#login {}
body.login div#login h1 {}
body.login div#login h1 a {}
body.login div#login form#loginform {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p label {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_login {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_pass {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.forgetmenot {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.forgetmenot input#rememberme {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.submit {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.submit input#wp-submit {}
body.login div#login p#nav {}
body.login div#login p#nav a {}
body.login div#login p#backtoblog {}
body.login div#login p#backtoblog a {}
```

Comment: The `login_headertitle` filter has been deprecated (as of version 5.2.0) in favour of the [`login_headertext`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_headertext/) filter, FYI.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I've updated/corrected my post accordingly. Cheers